# Is it possible to get a URL from a JSON file to display an image from img src

Tags: php, html, json

(note: new to json) I have a JSON file that contains image URLs inside of it (https://pastebin.com/TavfuziF), with the following code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<body>
    <center>
<?php 

$jdata = file_get_contents("cats-in-moviesnew.json");
//decode the retrieved json file into an array
$contents = json_decode($jdata, true);

echo
//create the table
"<table style border=3px solid black; ><tr><th>Producer</th><th>Director</th><th>Title</th><th>Year made</th><th>URL</th><th>Image</th><th>Poster URL</th></tr>";


//filling the table
foreach($contents as $record) {
echo
"<tr>
<td>" . $record["fields"]["produced_by"] . "</td>
<td>" . $record["fields"]["directed_by"] . "</td>
<td>" . $record["fields"]["title"] . "</td>
<td>" . $record["fields"]["year"] . "</td>
<td>" . $record["fields"]["url"] . "</td>
<td>" . 

$record["fields"]["url_poster"]

. "</td>
<td>" . $record["fields"]["url_poster"] . "</td>

</tr>";
}
?>
</body>
</center>
  
</html>
```

and Ive been trying to figure out if its possible to do something like <img src="$record["fields"]["url_poster"]"> (currently where the gap is in the table filling bit) inside that code is possible or not. Ive tried several things which haven't worked for me, Ive seen things talking about converting stuff to base64 but it's very complicated for me at my level, and I don't know what else to do at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can do that.  If it's not working, output the value to ensure it contains the path you're expecting.  Just watch your quotes.

Comment: Please add the json to the question instead of as a link off-site or the question won't be helpful for future visitors when the link expires. You don't need to post the whole thing, just take a few example items to show the format.

Comment: Try [`print_r($record);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to get an idea of what your data looks like, and how to access it.

Answer (score 1):

nevermind I figured it out just needed to add {} before the $record["fields"]["url_poster"], so it looks like: `"<img src={$record["fields"]["url_poster"]}>"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($contents as $record){
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><img src="'.$record['fields']['poster_url'].'" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '<table';
```

and just a piece of advice, use indentation on you code so in the feature someone handle the code it is more easier to read and easier to debug. :)